# How can I scroll dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList to a particular item dojo 1.7.2?

Tags: list, mobile, scroll, dojo

I'm using a dojox.mobile.Opener to select an action from an ActionSheet.
The Action sheet should operate on an item inside an EdgeToEdgeList below that opener.

After the user selects an item, and clicks the open ActionSheet button, I would like to scroll the EdgeToEdgeList so that the selected item is at the top of the screen (not under the opener).

Does anyone have any idea how I can programmatically ask the EdgeToEdgeList to scroll up to a particular item.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM node's scrollIntoView() method.

Generic browser version:

```
document.getElementById('NodeIdToScrollTo').scrollIntoView();
```

Dojo version:

```
dojo.byId('NodeIdToScrollTo').scrollIntoView();
```

or if you would rather go via widget id:

```
dijit.byId('NameOfListItem').domNode.scrollIntoView();
```